# I ran into the error 'Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) '

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I wanted to import Google Maps for my project. I am using Expo framework for it. Before running the app. I made sure that I installed map form 'react-native-maps'.

Here the code for HomeMap/index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const HomeMap = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

export default HomeMap;
```

Then, there are code for HomeScreen/index.js where I import my HomeMap:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import HomeMap from '../../components/HomeMap';

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <HomeMap />
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

After that I cann HomeScreen from my main page, that will be displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Aajm.png)